# How to remove the location updates in service class in android?

Tags: android, service, gps, locationlistener

I have a location listener class and a service class. In my location listener class I am starting GPS and I am keep getting the location every 10 seconds. My requirement is to stop the GPS location updates every day by 7PM . I am trying to stop the GPS updates in service using removeupdates but it is not working. How can i achieve this. Below is my code.

LocationGPS.java

```
public class LocationGPS extends Activity implements  LocationListener {
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
public static LocationManager locationManager;     
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10*1000 , 0 ,this);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PIService.class);
            PendingIntent   sevenPMIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); 
            //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, sevenPMIntent);

}

@Override     
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got new location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}    

@Override  
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}   

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}      
}
```

PIService.java

```
public class PIService extends Service{

@Override    
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;
}        
@Override     
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{     
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); 
    //Get the system current time.
    Date dt = new Date();
    int hours = dt.getHours();   

    //Compare the current time with 7PM 
    if(hours == 19){
        //if current time is 7PM
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now the time is 7PM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        LocationGPS.locationManager.removeUpdates(new LocationGPS()); //here is the place i am trying to remove the location updates.

    } 
    }


    return START_STICKY;      
}  

}
```

Comment: Refer this Question this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458070/android-locationmanager-removeupdateslistener-not-removing-location-listener

Comment: Instead of getting the location in frequent interval in background, how can I get the location in background, while the location is changed only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mLocationListeners.length specify this how get list of listeners

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onDestroy() 
 { 
 locationManager.removeUpdates(this); 
super.onDestroy(); 
 }
```